# PHP - Insert XML into MySQL db with a new column

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I've a phpx file which imports rows of a xml file.
My problem is that I have to insert one column more in my MySQL db.
I added a new column and edited the phpx file (which executes correctly), but the rows of the new column stays empty.

**Here is a tiny XML-example:**

```
<recordset>
    <job created_on="2013-01-22 11:07:12">
        <id>123456</id>
        <title>Name of the job (m/w)</title>
        <land>Swiss</land>
        <date>18.03.2014</date>
    </job>
</recordset>
```

**Here is my phpx insert function:**

```
    // insert into database
private function insertDataIntoDb()
{
    // truncate table
    $sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE '.$this->dbTable.';';
    $dbStatement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $dbStatement->execute();

    // insert data into table
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->dbTable.' (id, title, land, date)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
    $dbStatement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $dbStatement->execute();
    $dbStatement->bind_param('issi', $id, $title, $land, $date);

    // do this for every 'job'
    for($i=0, $l=count($this->strXml->job); $i<$l; $i++)
    {
        // xml handle
        $h = $this->strXml->stellenangebot[$i];
        // bind data for insert sql statement
        $id = utf8_decode(filter_var(html_entity_decode($h->id, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)); 
        $title= utf8_decode(filter_var(html_entity_decode($h->title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES));
        $land= utf8_decode(filter_var(html_entity_decode($h->land, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES)); 
                    $date= utf8_decode(filter_var(html_entity_decode($h->date, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES)); 

        // execute sql statement
        $dbStatement->execute();
        $this->dbNumOfRows += $dbStatement->affected_rows;
    }
}
```

As I said before, the new jobs will inserted, except the new column `land`!

Best Regards

Please help me !

Comment: And have you verified that within your loop `$land` actually contains a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is 2 fold, first you are not checking for any errors in your database access code and second, the bind_param requires the variables to exists at the time it is called. It binds the variable to the statement, not the value. Since your variables do not exis until after you do the bind_param that is probably your problem.

Also you seem to have an erroneous ->execute() as well.

I have not added error processing code but try this see if it works a little better.

```
private function CheckForErrors()
{
    // add error processing code here
}


// insert into database
private function insertDataIntoDb()
{
    // truncate table
    $sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE '.$this->dbTable.';';
    $dbStatement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    if ( ! $dbStatement->execute() ) {
       $this->CheckForErrors();
    }

    // insert data into table

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->dbTable.' (id, title, land, date)
                                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
    if ( ! $dbStatement = $this->db->prepare($sql) ) {
       $this->CheckForErrors();
    }

    //$dbStatement->execute();

    // Create the variables to be used in the bind_param()
    $id = '';
    $title = '';
    $land = '';
    $date = '';
    if ( ! $dbStatement->bind_param('issi', $id, $title, $land, $date) ) {
       $this->CheckForErrors();
    }

    // do this for every 'job'
    for($i=0, $l=count($this->strXml->job); $i<$l; $i++)
    {
        // xml handle
        $h = $this->strXml->stellenangebot[$i];
        // bind data for insert sql statement
        $id    = utf8_decode(filter_var(html_entity_decode($h->id, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)); 
        $title = utf8_decode(filter_var(html_entity_decode($h->title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES));
        $land  = utf8_decode(filter_var(html_entity_decode($h->land, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES)); 
        $date  = utf8_decode(filter_var(html_entity_decode($h->date, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'), FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES)); 

        // execute sql statement
        if ( ! $dbStatement->execute() ) {
           $this->CheckForErrors();
        }

        // this also seems a little unnecessary as an insert will only ever create one row
        // unless it fails and creates NO rows.
        // $this->dbNumOfRows += $dbStatement->affected_rows;
        $this->dbNumOfRows++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your hint that i have to crate variables solved my problem!